# Effect of Script tag inside HTML comment

Tags: xss, javascript, firefox, html

I recently participated in a CTF and solution of that CTF is based on this weird behavior of browser.

In First case when I am including script tag inside an HTML comment and without closing that comment then the browser(Firefox) assumes whole content after that as comment including body part. And no alert is popped.

Code:

```
<script>
alert(1);
<!--<script
alert(2);
</script>
<body>Hello</body>
```

Browser:

[image]

In Second all code is same except I removed script tag from comment now browser ending comment at that position and all other code executed smoothly. Both alert popped 1,2

Code:

```
<script>
alert(1);
<!--
alert(2);
</script>
<body>Hello</body>
```

Browser:

[image]

So I have two questions.

1. In first case when browser is assuming code in next lines as comment why even alert(1) is not popped?
2. Second why browser having different boundaries of HTML comment based on script Tag?

Please answer them or point to any resources. And feel free to modify question, I am new to this field and might have added some rubbish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is something to do with browser's HTML validating technique. Browser is trying to close missing tags.

[Do browsers automatically insert missing HTML tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26850250/do-browsers-automatically-insert-missing-html-tags)

Like in first case adding missing closing tag of HTML comment, and converts whole document as comment. But why it is doing differently in first and second case. I think that's why it is said that complexity creates problems. Browser is trying to be too smart and tripping over own feet. No other reason.

Answer (score 1):

An interesting situation indeed. First of all, it must be noted that we cannot nest `<script>` tags.
In the first case

```
alert(1);
<!--<script
alert(2);
</script>
<body>Hello</body>
```

the `<script` has `>` missing. Even with that it won't work. However, if we replace it with `</script>`, alert(1) runs. 
The second case is the same as this with `alert(2)` included within the `<script>` tags.

Comment: Why comment is ending at the same place in second case, while in first case it covering whole document as comment.